# What do we call these containers used in biotechnology?

Tags: terminology

I'm translating an autoclave instruction from Russian, and it says that these containers (ванночки) (see the black circle on the below photo) are to be sterilized in the autoclave. I'm not sure what they are called in English-language biotech texts.

The Russian text uses the vague term "ванночки", literally "little bathtubs". Maybe just "containers"?

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be a **Reagent Reservoir**, or just a *Reservoir*. These tall and narrow ones are specifically designed for use with a robot, but there are also shorter and wider ones for manual pipettes:

[image]

[120 mL Reagent Reservoirs](https://www.hamiltoncompany.com/automated-liquid-handling/consumables/reagent-reservoirs/120-ml-reagent-reservoirs)